# Iterate an array and validate elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the best way to iterate an array, validate each element and then return does this array is valid in Ruby? Something like:

```
def arr_valid?(arr)
  result = true
  arr.each do |element|
    result = false if
       # validate element with some requirments
    end
  end
  result
end
```

I think there is a lot of code for this approach above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), which will return `true` only if the block is `true` for all elements.

```
def arr_valid?(arr)
  arr.all? do |element|
    # validate element with some requirments
  end
end
```

Comment: If you find yourself using `not` or `!` to invert the sense of the block, use `none?` instead of `all?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def arr_valid?(arr)
  # there can't be Fixnums
  !arr.map {|v| v.is_a? Fixnum}.reduce {|a,b| a||b}
end

puts arr_valid? [1, 2, 3, 4] # >> false

puts arr_valid? ['1', '2', '3'] # >> true
```